# Jest .toBeCalledWith objectContaining not matching expect on received

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, automated-tests

I am trying to partially match the object which are being passed to `TitleRepo.find`. I am not able to understand what wrong I am doing.

[image]

```
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: ObjectContaining {"filter": {"limit": Any<Number>}}
Received: {"filter": {"title_ids.xxx.deleted_at": null, "title_ids.xxx.deleted_at": null, "title_ids.xxx.id": {"$exists": true, "$ne": null}}, "limit": 10, "sort": {"created_at": -1}}

Number of calls: 1

  31 |         });
  32 | 
> 33 |         expect(TitleRepo.find).toBeCalledWith(
     |                                ^
  34 |             expect.objectContaining({"filter": {"limit": expect.any(Number)}}),
  35 |         );
  36 |     })

  at Object.<anonymous> (tests/query/TitleQuery.test.js:33:32)
```

Related lines from test is.

```
TitleRepo.find = jest.fn();

it('should able to set platform correctly', async () => {
        const titles = await TitleQuery.find({
            platform: 'chandu'
        });

        expect(TitleRepo.find).toBeCalledWith(
            expect.objectContaining({"filter": {"limit": expect.any(Number)}}),
        );
    })
```

Comment: It's `expect.objectContaining({"filter": expect.objectContaining({"limit": expect.any(Number)})})` in your case.

Comment: @EstusFlask I edited as you suggest but still doesn't work  `Expected: ObjectContaining {"filter": ObjectContaining {"limit": Any<Number>}}`

Comment: @EstusFlask it work!! thank you. please post as answer , I'll accept. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`limit` property is on the same level as `filter`.

It should be:

```
expect(TitleRepo.find).toBeCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({ limit: expect.any(Number) })
```